# Raspberry Pi 2 (programmer) can not detect my Arduino via USB, even with alamode installed

Tags: usb, pi-2, arduino

I am working on a project where I am using a Raspberry Pi to program an Arduino Nano 328.  I have used the following commands (more or less) to create a useful environment on the Pi:

Install commands:

```
### Arduino
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install arduino

### Serial Config
$ wget https://github.com/wyolum/alamode/blob/master/bundles
  /alamode-setup.tar.gz?raw=true -O alamode-setup.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf alamode-setup.tar.gz
$ cd alamode-setup
$ sudo ./setup


### LAMP
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-dev php5-mysql mysql-server


## WiringPi
$ cd ~
$ git clone git://git.drogon.net/wiringPi
$ cd wiringPi
$ ./build

### www permissions
sudo chmod -R 777 var/www


## php IDE
sudo apt-get install geany
```

Now, when I plug my Arduino into the Pi, and open the Arduino programmer, the serial connection never appears in the Tool menu.  I have tried every variation that I can thing of, of opening the programmer, unplugging/plugging the Arduino and pressing the reset button.  Has anyone ever faced this problem before?

Also, I have a 5 volt, 3amp transformer that is connect to both the Arduino (Vin, ground) and the Pi (pin4 (5v) pin6(ground).  Both power up fine.  The Pi runs witout problems and the Arduino plays the default 'flashing' program.

The I/O lights on the Arduino do not respond or flash when the Arduino is plugged in, and the Pi shows no evidence that anything has happened either.  The Arduino does power up and runs that last program that was loaded onto it.

Comment: Have you checked https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/troubleshooting#toc1

Comment: Does anything appear in the output of `lsusb` or `dmesg` after plugging the Arduino in?

Comment: @Wilf The I/O lights on the Arduino do not respond or flash when the Arduino is plugged in, and the Pi shows no evidence that anything has happened either.  The Arduino does power up and runs that last program that was loaded onto it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue with the FTDI Drivers:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8010
http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Linux/ReadMe-linux.txt